# Wrong Behaviour of Snippets in Atom

Tags: atom-editor, code-snippets

I have created the following snippets in atom:

```
'.plain.text':
    'cdot':
        'prefix': '\c'
        'body': '\cdot'
    'vec':
        'prefix': '\v'
        'body': '\vec{$1}$2'
    'equation':
        'prefix': '\e'
        'body': """
            \begin{equation}

            $1

            \end{equation}

            """
```

The problem is that when I invoke them the first one appears correct, the second doesn't appears at all and the third one appears as:

```
\egin{equation}
end{equation}
```

Why is that happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove backslash `\` from prefixes (or customize with other characters which work)
- Use double-escape (`\\\\`) when you want them to show on `body`.

Snippet:

```
'.plain.text':
  'cdot':
    'prefix': 'c'
    'body': '\\\\cdot'
  'vec':
    'prefix': 'v'
    'body': '\\\\vec{$1}$2'
  'equation':
    'prefix': 'equation'
    'body': """
        \\\\begin{equation}

        $1

        \\\\end{equation}
    """
```

Note cursors will appear as desired but are moved in the images just to show snippet extension appearing.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the snippet prefix will not extend and it's also likely that's what's breaking the other 2, I'd suggest finding an alternative way to reference them with conventional characters.

Comment: You could do something like `c\\c`, `v\\v` & `e\\e`, or inverting orders like "c\\", "v\\" & "e\\", simply avoid starting with the slash, it will break it.

Comment: I will but why the backslash is causing so much trouble?